# How to inject html into webpage with chrome extension on button click

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have this in my popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
     <button id="button">Starting Now</button>
     <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
     <script src="popup.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my popup.js so far...

```
function dothis(){
  /* ??? */
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', dothis);
});
```

I want to inject a bit of html code into the web page on button click; I've already included it in my manifest. How do I do this? Sorry, I'm new to this! I've looked around on stack overflow, but I could really understand any of the answers. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is that "bit of code" stored, and what's in it?

Comment: the code is stored in an html file, and it's just the html code for a rectangle. I just wanted to see if I could inject it into the body of a webpage

Answer (score 3):

You need a [Content Script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) in order to interact with the page.  You can send a message from the popup to the content script with [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging), then the content script can do the actual interaction with the page.